# Understanding the WriteStream in Node.js

Tags: node.js, logging

Recently I wrote a small multi room chat application using Node.js and Socket.IO and I log the sent messages into different files depending on the room they occured in. At the moment I am using a number of writeStreams (one for each room) to archive this functionality, but while it works, I have been wondering if this is actually how writeStreams are supposed to be used.

My concerns:

1. When I first implemented writeStream it seemed the perfect match as instead of writing entire files it just wrote messages whenever a new one is posted - in retrospective however I am not sure if having 10-20 Streams open all the time is ideal.
2. Currently I use the .end() function when the last User leaves a room, but aside from a callback function I can't use in this case, there seems to be no way of telling if all messages have been written already when calling end(), which brings me right back to 1. and the questions if I am actually using writeStreams as they are meant to be used.

I guess my question is... can/should writeStreams be used for logging purposes in such a case? Are those actually hogging resources while waiting for input or is it save to have a large number open for extended periods of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to point 2 I can be quick: When you call `.end()` on a writeStream, the stream no longer accepts new writes, but does finish writing the data it has to the filesystem. So you don't have to worry about losing part of your chat log - unless an error occurs of course (for that, listen to the 'error' event of the stream).

And With regards to point 1: I don't believe there is anything wrong with keeping file system streams open for longer periods of time. Plenty of applications do that to write their logs, for instance. One possible problem I do see with your setup, is that as the amount of data your chat system handles grows, you might generate chat logs faster then you can write them to the file system. If that happens, your streams will start buffering more and more data and eventually your process will run out of memory and crash. Of course this depends on your data volumes.

Comment: I am not too worried about the data volume... I would be surprised if there were more than 30 people in the chat at any given moment. Thanks for the answer, really helped me, especially the bit about .end()